# Get Coordinates of Nested MovieClip in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, nested, coordinates, point

I need to get the coordinates of a nested MovieClip in Actionscript 3.

Here's the context:

> Stage > Container > MovieClip1 > MovieClip2

I'm aiming to get MovieClip2's coordinates (x and y) according to Container. I've tried localToGlobal but it does not seem to work as expected.

**EDIT:**

This is the code I've tried within MovieClip1's class:

```
var globalPoint:Point = new Point(MovieClip2.x, MovieClip2.y);
globalPoint = Container.localToGlobal(globalPoint);
```

Comment: Can you post the code you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MovieClip2`'s position is relative to `MovieClip1`, so you need to get `MovieClip1` to convert it to a global point (relative to `Stage`) first, then convert that global point to `Container`'s coordinate space:

```
var clipLocalPoint:Point = new Point(MovieClip2.x, MovieClip2.y);
var globalPoint:Point = MovieClip1.localToGlobal(clipLocalPoint);
var containerLocalPoint:Point = Container.globalToLocal(globalPoint);
```

More simply, you can get a global point by converting a default `Point`, which is at (0, 0), from `MovieClip2`'s coordinate space:

```
var globalPoint:Point = MovieClip2.localToGlobal(new Point());
var containerLocalPoint:Point = Container.globalToLocal(globalPoint);
```